# ¿Cómo agregar contenido a un etiqueta HTML sin borrar el contenido que ya tenía?

Tags: javascript, html

lo que quiero es añadir contenido a una etiqueta HTML (específicamente un label) con JS, sin sobrescribir el contenido que ya tenía en mi etiqueta. El código que tengo es este [

```
    <form action="">
        <label for="range">Estas en el rango: </label>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" id="range">
    </form>
    <script>
        const rango = document.getElementById("range");
        const label = document.querySelector("label")
        rango.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            label.innerHTML = `Estas en el rango: ${rango.value}` 
            console.log(rango.value)
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad 'innerText' para referirte al texto dentro del label, y puedes concatenar (sumar) un string:

```
elementoLabel.innerText += string
```

Espero que te funcione!

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero tengo otro problema. A la segunda vez de intentarlo se me hace un cantidad muy grande de números 